# How to change nsstring to nsdate format in iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate

I have struggling with to convert nsstring to nsdate format. I have a date in nsstring format like (2011-08-25 18:30:00 +0000), but i want to change it in nsdate format (08/26/2011). How to change it? Can any one help me please? Thanks in advance... I have spend one day to solve this but i cant find out the solution.. Please help me friends....

This is my code,

```
    NSString *dateString = @"2011-08-25 18:30:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Converted date is %@",dateFromString);
```

Output is,

```
         Converted date is (null)
```

Yuva.M

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString *dateWithInitialFormat = @"2011-08-25 18:30:00 +0000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateWithInitialFormat];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *dateWithNewFormat = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateWithNewFormat: %@", dateWithNewFormat);
```

From NSLog: dateWithNewFormat: 08/25/2011

See [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Thank you Mr.CocoaFu. Its returning fine. But, i want to pass one parameter to webservice in date format, nsstring is not acccepting. Can you help me? Please, today is the last date for this task. Please.

Comment: Check the Date Format Patterns link I provided, that should be what you need along with the sample code I provided.  But if you are stuck provide more information.  Also, please accept my answer if it is correct and helpful.

Comment: Ya your answer is very helpful. Am not familiar in iphone developing, so am struggling. Is there any sample code related to my problem. Once again thank you.

Comment: YOu might want to watch the WWDC11 video on dates.  NSDate is just seconds since a reference time.  NSCalendar understands calendars, months, days, etc. and may be what you are missing.

Comment: So once we have NSDate, we can take new NSDateFormatter in any format and convert that date into any format, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, create an string representation of the date in the format specified with `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an NSDateFormatter and set the date format to match how you're storing it, like the below.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: myDateString];
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Nicholas, i have edited my question. Please look at this. I have tried that code, but i cant get an answer. Can you solve my problem. Please.

Comment: Your date format is wrong, it needs to match the format you're putting into it then it'll store it in it's own style.

Comment: ok friend.. am still trying to solve this. thank you for spending time with me.. i'll update my answer once i solved this.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    NSDate* d = [df dateFromString:@"January 06, 1992"];
    NSLog(@"%@", d);

    NSDate *dispalyDate = d;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
    NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dispalyDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
```