# How to format date 12/2/31 H, 2:21:41 AM in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter, ios13

This is what date I am getting again our current date of 2019.

```
12/2/31 H, 2:21:41 AM
```

Can anyone help me how can I parse this date to NSDate object in Objective-c?

Comment: NSString to NSDate convert, you could refer to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204748/how-to-change-nsstring-to-nsdate-format-in-iphone

Comment: @pqteru try to check my date format and date format in the link which you shared. Both are different.
Also right now we have 2019 is going on but here it show 31. so we don't know its calendar type as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calendar format belongs to the Japanese Calendar.

To parse the date with `NSDateFormatter` you have to replace the `H` with `Heisei` and assign a Japanese Calendar instance to the date formatter.

```
NSString *dateString = [@"12/2/31 H, 2:21:41 AM" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"H" withString:@"Heisei"];
NSCalendar *japanese = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierJapanese];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US@calendar=japanese"];
formatter.calendar = japanese;
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/d/yy G, h:mm:ss a";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```